# write a method to decide if one is a permutation of the other in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am new to programming and I written down a solution as below. Is there a any way I can write down a better solution for this problem?

```
def arePermutation(s1, s2):
  if len(s1) != len(s2):
   print 'length should be the same'
  return

  arr1 = []
  arr2 = []

  for i in range(len(s1)):
    arr1.append(s1[i])

  for i in range(len(s2)):
    arr2.append(s2[i])

  if set(arr1) == set(arr2):
    print 'One string is permutaion of another'
  else:
    print 'Not permutation of another'
  return

#arePermutation('rav', 'var')
#arePermutation('dog', 'ogd')
arePermutation('abcdeff', 'abcjklm')
```

Comment: better to sort and compare for equality.

Comment: First, you're not returning anything. Second, you have unnecessary for loops, `arr1 == s1`. Third, what if you have "AAAB" and "ABBB"? Both are the same length, and `set('AAAB')==set('ABBB')`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since this code doesn't work.  Try

```
arePermutation("aaab", "bbba")
```

Instead, make a list of the characters in each string.  Sort the lists.  If the lists are equal, then the strings are permutations of one another (anagrams).

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of unnecessary code. Plus you need to sort instead of form sets, in case there are duplicated characters. There's no reason to copy s1 and s2 into the new lists arr1 and arr2, because `sorted()` will work over a string because it is a sequence of characters. Also, if you aren't returning a value then there's no need to have a return statement at the end. So this simpler code works fine:

```
def arePermutation(s1, s2):
  if sorted(s1) == sorted(s2):
    print 'One string is permutation of another'
  else:
    print 'Not permutation of another'
```

Also, it would generally be a good idea to make this sort of function just return a boolean, and do the printing outside in a separate function.